# Setting up Magento Cloud local development environment - Docker

Tags: magento2.2.2, magento2-enterprise, cloud

I'm having issues when it comes to setting up a docker development environment for Magento Commerce Cloud.

#### I followed steps described here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/setup/first-time-setup.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/docker/docker-development.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/docker/docker-config.html
https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud

and I got up and running latest, empty Magento Commerce (Cloud) 2.2.6.
Nothing out of the ordinary.

Then I tried to repeat those steps to create working environment for the project (2.2.2) I'm currently working on.
I cloned the project using `magento-cloud get ************* -e development` and copied `docker-compose.yml` file and `docker` directory from the clean template directory to project directory.

I expected everything would work the same, but a bunch of errors popped up.

#### Errors

*#1*  Command: `docker-compose run build cloud-build`
*#1*  Result:
`[Magento\MagentoCloud\Filesystem\FileSystemException]
The directory "/var/www/magento/var" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/var/www/magento/var): Device or resource busy`

After giving *sudo* to command above the error was slightly different

*#2*  Command: `sudo docker-compose run build cloud-build`
*#2*  Result:
`[RuntimeException]
Command git apply /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/ece-tools/patches/locker-process.patch returned code 1`

How do I get over these errors? Is there something crucial I'm missing here? Could it be that there is an issue inside the actual project code?

Thanks in advance